# RGeo contains? on Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rgeo

I need to find all the instances of a class `Place` where its polygon attribute contains a point supplied, as in `Place.for_point(pt)`.

==== added ====

Ok, I can get this query to execute, but with the wrong result:

```
Place.all.where("ST_Contains(poly, ST_Point(#{up_pt.join(',')}))")
Place Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "places".* FROM "places" WHERE (ST_Contains(poly, ST_Point(25.1,25.09999999999999))) LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

It seems clear that the coordinates are correctly supplied: the coordinates in the point supplied are in latlon format. But the coordinates are from the centroid of one of the polygons in the table, so they should be inside that polygon, and that means I should be getting a returned set of Place records... But I'm not.

Why? What am I missing?

Here's the polygon I'm expecting to contain the point:

```
f.unproject(Place.last[:poly])
  Place Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "places".* FROM "places" ORDER BY "places"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<RGeo::Geographic::ProjectedPolygonImpl:0x3fcdc30f807c "POLYGON ((24.999999999999996 24.999999999999996, 25.2 24.999999999999996, 25.2 25.20000000000001, 24.999999999999996 25.20000000000001, 24.999999999999996 24.999999999999996))">
irb(main):134:0>
```

==== original post ====

I cannot get my head around how to structure this. For an individual instance I have a method `contains?(pt)` as an instance method of `Place` that works fine when called as `place.contains?(@f.project(@pt_inside))` and `@pt_inside` is defined thusly: `@pt_inside = @f.point(25.1,25.1)`, where @f is the factory for the object.

The schema for `Place` looks like this:

```
  create_table "places", force: :cascade do |t|
t.geometry "loc", limit: {:srid=>3857, :type=>"st_point"}
t.geometry "poly", limit: {:srid=>3857, :type=>"st_polygon"}
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
```

end

My rails is very rusty, but I cannot make a query to the class Place work....

Comment: What is in the body of `def contains?`? how can we help you convert it into a query if we don't know how it works? ;)

Comment: I'm not being snarky, but I wasn't sure that the internal mechanics of a method that doesn't work would be very helpful... I get what you're saying and I can post it later (not at the computer with the code now). But the the goal is clearly stated: to find the polygons contained an an object, based on the point that's the argument....

Answer (score 1):

Per Taryn's request, here's the functioning instance method that returns a binary response to determine if the current object's `:poly` attribute contains the point

```
def contains? pt
    self[:poly].contains?(pt)
end
```

Obviously trivial. The problem I'm having is that when a class method is used to see which, if any instances' poly attributes contain the point, I'm lost....

```
def self.for_point pt
    where([:poly].contains?(pt))
end
```

This is just the last, reductive, desperate attempt. Obviously, what needs to happen is that each object must have a the instance method called on it, but that's basically a Ruby loop, seems insane to do that, traverse a table with potentially millions of entries....

I can't quite get the sql-based syntax that examples show, but in any case, the instance method is pure Ruby, why do I need to drop into sql on a class query, I ask myself? Or do I?

Also: I previously wrote code like this without an RGeo gem, so I was checking bounding boxes, which is pretty easy to do, and would be fine since all such queries will be based on rectangular areas based on areas with vertical and horizontal boundaries. But I'm using the gem for a reason, to avoid lots of functions and hackery that I have to maintain...

Comment: Fair enough - I didn't realise it was such a simple method :D